# Checkboxes always return checked whether they are or not

Tags: jquery

The HTML:

```
<div id="appcheck">
  <input class="precheck" type="checkbox" /> 
  <input class="precheck" type="checkbox" />
  <input class="precheck" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

The jQuery that is supposed to discover unchecked results. Always returns 3 `not checked` no matter how many boxes are checked.

```
$('input.precheck').each(function() {
  if($(this).not(':checked')) {
    console.log('not checked');
  }
});
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `$(this).not(':checked')`, as a jQuery object, is "truthy" and will thus satisfy that `if` regardless of how many elements it represents. On the other hand, functions such as `.is` return booleans. This is all well-covered in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), ready for you to read.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, well that explains a lot. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  `is` + negation operator instead of `not`. `not` doesn't return a boolean value; it returns a jQuery object and your if statement is always true.

```
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
```

or:

```
if (!this.checked) {
```

You can also code:

```
var notChecked = $('input.precheck').filter(function(){
   return !this.checked;
}).length;
```